# Auto-scale content, header and other font sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I found the great site with this technique – http://www.informationarchitects.jp/en/
When you change screen width, site auto-scales its content (font-size, position of elements, etc.).

So we have proper view of content on every monitor, not that ugly little font on HD (1980*1280) monitors which can be seen on every 960px wide sites. I mean if you do not zoom in (ctrl + +) 960 px wide site on your HD monitor, font remains very small.

So the question is: **is there some common solution to make auto-scaling sites? Or every case must be made in its unique way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site is using CSS Media Queries to adapt the layout to screen size. You can read the spec here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

alistapart had a great article on it a while back that serves as a primer on working with media queries: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/